# Remotely viewing IP camera on Belkin N450 DB router

Tags: router, ip, camera

I need to setup a wireless IP camera (Trendnet TV-IP501W) on my network so that it is remotely visible from anywhere. Right now I successfully connected it to my home network but nothing else. My router is a Belkin N450 DB.

Any help would be much appreciated, including what this would be referred to as so I could more easily ask another forum. I believe it is something like "port forwarding" but I'm not sure.

---

Ok, I believe I found this in the "virtual servers" section. It asks for enabling with a check box, description, inbound port, type, private IP, & private port.
In that order I have checked enabling, "camera", 150, TCP, 81, and 81? I'm assuming inbound ports are the numbers I use for the home network - xxx.xxx.x.150 and the 81 was for private.

I used my WAN IP and added :81 and .81 but didn't get it. What am I doing wrong?

---

Ok, I believe I found this in the "virtual servers" section. It asks for enabling with a check box, description, inbound port, type, private IP, & private port.
In that order I have checked enabling, "camera", 150, TCP, 81, and 81? I'm assuming inbound ports are the numbers I use for the home network - xxx.xxx.x.150 and the 81 was for private.

I used my WAN IP and added :81 and .81 but didn't get it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mike, we reset the ownership of this post to your account, so you can now [edit] it to add more information. You should [register your account](http://superuser.com/users/login?noauto=true&returlUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent) permanently so that in the future, you will always have access to your questions no matter where you log in from.

Answer (score 0):

Port Forwarding or Single Port Forwarding. You probably want to give the camera a static IP address. On the router the port forwarding tab will have fields for: Application - create a new application 'Camera', Set External Port No to an unused Port Number, 81 will do, Set Internal Port No to whatever your camera uses, probably 80. Set the internal IP address to the static IP you have assigned the camera. To connect from a web browser external to your network you will need your router IP (or dyndns address) followed by :81 - so assuming your router was 104.68.44.5 you stick 104.68.44.5:81 in the browser address bar. At your router anything trying to connect to port 81 gets connected to port 80 on the internal IP you specified.